# Having issues getting RegEx to work in bash script. Condition never passes.

Tags: regex, bash

I have a simple script that should return an error message if $Msg doesn't begin with "TST-" followed by some numbers followed by a space. I know the regular expression works as I have taken it from a ruby script where it was behaving as I expected.

I have the below block of code and I don't understand why it's not doing what I'd expect. I have read a lot of other answers to similar questions, but none of them seem to solve my issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

Msg="TST-3 test string"
#regEx="^TST-\d+\s.*"
if [[ ! $Msg =~ ^TST-\d+\s.* ]]; then
    echo >&1 "Message must begin with TST-XXXX followed by a space"
    exit 1
fi
```

$Msg is set to "TST-3 test string" yet it still returns the error message and I really don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d` and `\s` is not available.

```
Msg="TST-3 test string"
regEx="^TST-[0-9]+ .*"
if [[ ! "${Msg}" =~  ${regEx}  ]]; then
    echo >&1 "Message must begin with TST-XXXX followed by a space"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `bash` does not support `\d` and `\s` operators to indicate digit and whitespace, respectively.

You need to use `[0-9]` (or `[:digit:]` for `locale` dependency) for digit, and character class `[:blank:]` for any horizontal whitespace or `[:space:]` for any kind of whitespace (or write the character class putting the desired whitespaces yourself).

```
$ Msg="TST-3 test string"
$ [[ ! $Msg =~ ^TST-[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]] ]] && echo 'No Match' || echo 'Match'
Match
```

Also, the `.*` after the whitespace match is redundant, you can drop that.